# Android fade in animation

Tags: android, animation, alpha

I would like to create a fade in Animation in android. The object should animate alpha around y axis. That means that it should create alpha from 0f to 1f in a clockwise circle.

I am using a custom ImageView which is a circle of course.

I have tried usin ObjectAnimator class but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I had created a fade in animation like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

    Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
            fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); //add this
            fadeIn.setDuration(2000);

            Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
            fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); //and this
            fadeOut.setStartOffset(1000);
            fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

            AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
            animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
            //animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
            logo.setAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: No, this is not what I need. The first problem is that I can not use Animation object because I have createad a custom ImageView which is already using animation for skew and only thing that works is ObjectAnimator class. The second thing is that I want the circle to fade in clockwise. I do not want the whole image to appear immediately. It needs to fade piece by piece

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do that, if it's a custom View you're probably going to have to write you're own method that draws a portion of the arc overriding the ondraw method.